# html2canvas | take screenshot of particular area

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

At the moment I am using html2canvas as a library to take screenshots of elements. In a new feature I am making I have to make a screenshot of an area (not an element). Is it even possible to do this in html2canvas and if not does anyone have any suggestions in which library this is possible?

Moreover, are you able to take a screenshot with html2canvas and showcase everything at the element's position, instead of just one element.

Kind regards,

Danny

Answer (score -1):

There is a ready https://github.com/jacobscarter/angular-feedback example for angular. You can just adapt it to your usage.